# An acceptable USB enclosure for a 2TB SATA Drive

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, sata, enclosures

I just got me [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822145276) 2TB SATA drive.
However, I can't seem to find an acceptable USB enclosure for it.  As I browse newegg or amazon, most of the enclosures state a maximum size drive (e.g. 1tb or 750gb) or don't state the max at all.

Can someone help out?

---

Ok, I got [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817173042&cm_re=sata_enclosure_3.5-_-17-173-042-_-Product) one.  It seems to have really good reviews. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore Max - as long as it is SATA/Sata2 compatible, you shouldn't have a problem. If you want, email the seller first to make sure.

Personally, I would just get the smallest enclosure you can find... but, if it is going to be left on 24x7, you may want to look for one with a fan included.

The only time to be careful of Max is when buying NAS units, but even most of them will support more.

Comment: i would neither ignore the manufacturer specifications myself nor would i publicly recommend such a thing. if the drive or the enclosure are getting damaged in the process neither will be covered by warranty ("the nice folks at SU told me to ignore the specs" may not qualify as an argument with customer care).

Comment: I did say email the seller first to make sure... Anyway, the maximum drive is usually written at the time of shipping which does not accommodate larger sizes. I have dealt with close to 150 enclosures from different manufacturers with nearly every chip from expensive ones (based on LSI and Adaptec) down to cheap unknown brand ones and as long as it is compatible with 3GB/s SATA2, I have **NEVER** had a problem, or seen any sort of damage.

Comment: @molly: if the drive is getting damaged you haven't matched up the interfaces properly.  stop trying to plug that SATA drive into a PATA interface, it won't work.